# PHP - Session variable being saved then deleted

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-variables

Currently working on a university assignment and for something that's so simple, I'm having a few issues with it.

I am using a customer session handler which stores the sessions in a database. When a user logs in, I store the email (used to log in) into a $_SESSION['email'] variable and then based on that, if the session is set then a user is logged in and redirected accordingly however, when I set the variable it saves to the database upon logging in but doesn't redirect and if I refresh the page the session_data in the database becomes empty as if it has been overwritten but I only ever declare $_SESSION['email'] in one place.

login.php

```
if($_POST) {

    try {

        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $user->logIn($email, $password);

    } catch(Exception $e) {

        $output = '<p>'. $e->getMessage() .'</p>';

    }

}
```

my $user->logIn function

```
public function logIn($name, $password) {

        $query = $this->dbConn->select('*', 'users')
                                ->where(array('email' => array('=', $name), 'password' => array('=', $password, 'AND')))
                                ->run();

        if($query > 0) {

            $_SESSION['email'] = $name;

        } else {

            throw new Exception('Details not found!');

        }

    }
```

I can set a $_SESSION variable outside of the login script and it saves fine but its just when I am saving the email variable that it seems to be stored then immediately deleted.

Any help would be highly appreciated thanks

Comment: Logic does not seem correct: `if($_SESSION) {

            $this->logOut();

            session_start();

        }` This would be FALSE everytime unless you call `session_start()` before hand. If it is FALSE then you don't call `session_start()`? I think you mean `if(!$_SESSION){}`

Comment: that was something my lecturer put in to test. It's not actually meant to be in there but either way it doesn't make s difference to my problem.

Comment: I suspect your IF statement is FALSE and the `$_SESSION['email']` is not getting populated. How about `$_SESSION['email'] = ""; if($query<0){ $_SESSION['email'] = $name; }` This will ensure the variable is set, but if the query gets results, the variable will get a value.

Comment: The variable does get populated as I see it enter into my database session_data however, when I refresh the page and then reload the database the session_data returns empty as if the session variable has been deleted if that makes sense?

Comment: That does make a little more sense. One of 2 things could be happening, as far as I can discern. 1) When you refresh, the variable is changed or unset somewhere else in your code after it's entered into your DB 2) your servers memory is cleared for your HTTP service for some reason. The latter is easy to check. Look in your error.log file for restarts of the service.

Comment: As far as I can see the variable isn't being unset anywhere in the code. It's only declared in the login function. As for the memory - I can set a session variable elsewhere outside of the login and it will save and not be cleared?